# Remove Overlapping Intervals & Divide into Non-overlapping Intervals Python

Tags: python, intervals, overlapping

I have a sorted list of intervals `List1`:
`[1,10], [2,4], [6,8], [20,30], [24,28], [35,40], [45,50]`

where I know that the overlapping intervals are `List2`: `[2,4], [6,8], [24,28]`

from which I want to get the non-overlapping intervals, such that the Output is: `[1,2], [4,6], [8,10], [20,24], [28,30], [35,40], [45,50]`

How can I do this efficiently in Python?

My first thought is that I should create a new list `List1` of divided intervals for every overlapping interval I come across in `List2`, and delete the corresponding element of `List2` (continue this until `List2` is empty), but I've been having some trouble getting this to work. This seems different in nature than many interval problems, so any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the most efficient way but it might be a good starting point for you:

```
data = [[1, 10], [2, 4], [6, 8], [20, 30], [24, 28], [35, 40], [45, 50]]
flat_data = sorted([x for sublist in data for x in sublist])
new_intevals = [flat_data[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(flat_data), 2)]

print(new_intevals)
# output: [[1, 2], [4, 6], [8, 10], [20, 24], [28, 30], [35, 40], [45, 50]]
```